# Division by zero when putting an ODE in standard form for analyzing singular points

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analyticity, singularity

Suppose we want to find the singular points of the ODE $\sin(x^2)y''+xy'+y=0$, where $0 \leq x \leq \pi/2$. We first seek to put the ODE in standard form $y''+a(x)y'+b(x) = 0$ so we can analyze $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ to find the singular points of the ODE. In this case, we divide through by $\sin(x^2)$. Since the ODE is specified for $0 \leq x \leq \pi/2$, wouldn't dividing by $\sin(x^2)$ be dividing by zero when $x = 0$? What is the best explanation for why doing this is valid? Is it because we have the trivial solution when $x = 0$?

Comment: Could be helpful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_singular_point

Comment: Thanks! My question actually had less to do with how to find singular points but more with why it's ok to divide by $\sin(x^2)$ given the domain of the problem. I've tried to explain myself better in a comment to the first answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is exactly because whenever $\sin(x^2)=0$ on this interval, $x=0$ and $y\equiv 0$.

To be formal, I would say, either $\sin(x^2)=0$ and 
$$
y\equiv 0,x\in[0,\pi/2]
$$
or we can divide through by $\sin(x^2)=0$.....

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for. As a follow-up, would it then be inconsistent to specify $y(0) = p,~p \neq 0$ as an initial condition to this problem?

Comment: @Rahul yes, because then $y\equiv 0$ would no longer be a solution.

Comment: Thanks! While I feel some of my questions may have been obvious, I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something. I'm not a maths major and so I sometimes worry that my reasoning may be invalidated due to a lack of knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

It's really not much different from any other case where $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ have singularities.  What matters is not the value at the point where $\sin(x^2) = 0$ but the limiting behaviour as $x$ approaches such a point.  As $x \to 0$, $\sin(x^2) \sim x^2$ so $x a(x) = x^2/\sin(x^2) \to 1$ while $x^2 b(x) = x^2/\sin(x^2) \to 1$.  This makes $x=0$ a  regular singular point.

Comment: Thanks! I understand how to find singular points and to consider the limiting case and so on. What I was questioning is why it's valid to divide by $\sin(x^2)$ given that it is zero when $x = 0$. Or perhaps a better way of asking my question would be, "is the trivial solution the only solution to the ODE when $x = 0$? And is this why it's ok to divide by $\sin (x^2)$?" If this is the case, a follow-up question might then be "Would it be inconsistent to specify $y(0) = p,~p \neq 0$ as an initial condition to this problem?".

Comment: The solutions to an ODE with a singular point often do not exist at the singular point (it will depend on the indicial roots in the regular case), and specifying initial conditions at the singular point is not a good idea.

Comment: Got it. Thanks!

Comment: I have another follow-up question based on your original answer that I'm hoping you can clarify. You concluded that $x = 0$ is a regular singular point by showing $xa(x) = x^2b(x) \to 1$ as $x \to 0$. Suppose $a(x) = 0$ and $b(x) = \frac{\ln(x)}{x}$. Then clearly $x = 0$ is a singular point. However, even though $x^2b(x) = x\ln(x) \to 0$ as $x \to 0$, $x = 0$ is an irregular singular point since $x\ln(x)$ is not analytic at $x = 0$. So it doesn't seem like analyzing the limiting behavior as you have done is a reliable approach. Are there any comments you'd care to make regarding this? Thanks!